# Which law is this expression X+ X’.Y=X+Y

Tags: boolean-algebra

Question. Name the law given and verify it using a truth table. X+ X’.Y=X+Y

```
My Answer. 
X   Y   X’  X’.Y    X+X’.Y  X+Y
0   0   1   0       0       0
0   1   1   1       1       1
1   0   0   0       1       1
1   1   0   0       1       1

Prove algebraically that X + X’Y = X + Y.
L.H.S. = X + X’Y
           = X.1 + X’Y        (X . 1 = X property of 0 and 1)
           = X(1 + Y) + X’Y   (1 + Y = 1 property of 0 and 1)
           = X + XY +  X’Y                                                             
           = X + Y(X + X’)
           = X + Y.1          (X + X’ =1 complementarity law)
           = X + Y            (Y . 1 = Y property of 0 and 1)
           = R.H.S.      Hence proved.
```

My teacher marked my answer wrong. And told me to find the correct answer. Friends tell me is it a *complementary law or distributive law or Absorption law?* If it is absorption kindly tell me how to prove RHS and LHS algebraically.

Comment: Your teacher may find your algebraic proof too complex (though it is correct, imho). For example, you use commutativity without need. Regarding the name of the law, I doubt very much it has one, but I would not underestimate the ability of people to create terminology just for the hell of it.

Comment: We call it Absorption law, the prove is in any decent textbook.

Comment: For me the absorption laws are $x \land (x \lor y) = x$ and $x \lor (x \land y) = x$.

Comment: Did you talk to your teacher before seeking solace on the internet?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer, but this seems to be called "Redundancy law". Check line 12 of this webpage: https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm

Answer (score 10):

One way of looking at this is as a consequence of distributivity, where $P+QR\equiv (P+Q)(P+R)$. Then you'll have
$$\begin{align}
X+(X'Y) &\equiv (X+X')(X+Y)&\text{distributivity}\\
&\equiv T(X+Y)&\text{inverse}\\
&\equiv X+Y&\text{domination} 
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Is this equation any way is Absorption law ? If yes then how to prove RHS and LHS algebraically

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the third distributive law (see, e.g., [this page](http://www.cbseguess.com/ebooks/xii/computer_science1/boolean_algebralaws.php)). I think your proof is correct

Comment: Hmm. I've been doing this stuff for decades and I've never come across the term "third distributive law".

Answer (score -4):

X+X'Y=X+Y

taking LHS
X+X'Y=(X+X')(X+Y)      OR distributes over AND
1.(X+Y)                (X+X'=1)
X+Y=RHS                1 is identity for AND

Hence Proved

Comment: I don't think this is the proof that the asker is looking for: it doesn't use the algebraic properties of the operators. Also, I find your proof very hard to read. What does "(X+Y)(X+X'=1)X+Y" mean?